# How do I define a custom collection in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

Following the [Jekyll Collections documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#documents), I wrote the following code in _config.yml

```
_config.yml

collections: 
- popular_posts
```

So when I print {{ site.collections }}, the output is "popular_posts".

I also made a folder called "_popular_posts" at the same level as "_posts".
_popular_posts contains two .md files with some YAML front matter, same as a post.

However, if I print {{ site.popular_posts }} or {{ site.collections.popular_posts }}, there is no output.

How do I have Jekyll recognize the .md files in that directory so that the following code will work?

```
{% for popular_post in site.popular_posts %}
  <a href="{{ popular_post.link }}">
    <h1>{{ popular_post.title }}</h1>
    <img class="pop-img" src="{{ popular_post.image_url }}">
  </a>
  <span id="pop-order"><span class="pop-current-popular_post-number">{{ popular_post.number }}</span>/5</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you set `output:` to `true`? I don't fully understand collections, but as I understand it, that is required to make Jekyll generate the collection items. Also note that the collections functionality is said to be in beta, and may not be fully functional yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy! You're on the right track. In your `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
- popular_posts
```

This will tell Jekyll to read in all the files in `_popular_posts`.

If you want each of those two files to have a corresponding output file (like how `_posts` works now), you'll want to change your `_config.yml` to:

```
collections:
  popular_posts:
    output: true
```

This will produce files at `/popular_posts/filename1.html` and `/popular_posts/filename2.html`, one page for each post.

Collections are [only recently up on GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0) so if you were trying this there, it would have failed.

Check out [jekyll-help](https://github.com/jekyll/help) for more help if you need it!